# Why does the C/++ scanf function need referenced variables as arguments?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference, scanf

Why does the C/++ scanf function need referenced variables as arguments? I was wondering why scanf can't just take in the variable itself, since it gave me a weird warning whenever I didn't put in a referenced variable. It thought I had put in a pointer. Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really specific to `scanf`. It's basic C. If you only pass in the variable and not an address of the variable then the function would not be able to change the original variable in the caller's scope. In C, variables are passed by value. So to change the original variable the function needs a pointer to it (and not a copy).

Comment: @kaylum yes, I just realised... I feel so stupid. Just one follow-up question that'll make me feel stupid again in 2 minutes. How is the function modifying the value inside of the specified address? If it stores it in a pointer, I don't see how they could modify the value. I'm sorry if this was a bit vague, I just don't understand how the function is modifying the value just based on the address. Could you provide the source code for the function (I don't know where to find it)? Thanks

Comment: Again, basic C. To change the contents that a pointer references the "dereference" operator, `*`, is used. `int my_int = 10; int *my_ptr = &my_int; *my_int = 20;`. Suggest you review a basic C book or tutorial as that will be covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't see how they could modify the value

Here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void changeNumber(int *n) {
  *n = 12;
}

int main() {  
  int x = 5; 
  printf("X: %i\n", x);
  changeNumber(&x);
  printf("X: %i", x);
  return 0; 
}
```

**Output**

```
X: 5
X: 12
```

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, scanf() functions are from C and required their arguments to be pointers because the original C did not have a pass-by-reference for parameters at all.

The programmer writing the function had to use pointers (which passed a memory address value) to achieve the result that pass-by-reference would have provided.

I learned to program with Pascal and this (along with the lack of array bounds-checking) was one of the most annoying things about C when I first learned it.

I believe C++ has pass-by-reference but the scanf functions are from the C language stdio so they pass parameters by value.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the difference between two `scanf` function below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void scanf_1(int a) {
    a = 5;
}

void scanf_2(int *a) {
    *a = 6;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 1;

    scanf_1(b);
    printf("(1) b = %d\n", b);
    scanf_2(&b);
    printf("(2) b = %d\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
(1) b = 1                                                                                                                                    
(2) b = 6
```

You can see, if you pass by value, the value of `b` is not changed. But when you use the pointer then pass by reference, the value of `b` is updated.